# How to convert string to unsigned long in C++?

Tags: c++, stdin, long-integer, unsigned, fgets

I need help in programming. The program has to accept a string that will eventually be turned to unsigned long. But here's the catch, there must be an error catcher that when you enter combination of hex and symbols like `a!!!!!!` will produce an error and the unsigned long variable must be able to accept and store the input greater that `4294967295` which is `FFFFFFFF`. I've tried this code segment:

```
char buffer[256];
unsigned long holder;
fgets(buffer,256,stdin);
holder = strtoul (buffer,NULL,16);
```

My problem is that when I enter `FFFFFFFFF` (9 F's) instead of `FFFFFFFF` (8 F's), the holder will STILL accept `4294967295` even though its more than the. Another thing is that when I combine both hex and symbols like `a!!!!!`, the `fgets` still consider the hex A.

Can you please give me an idea on how to do this? If you know any other idea besides this code, please do let me know. Thanks!

Comment: [`std::stoul`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stoul). Will throw an exception if the conversion failed.

Comment: The problem is that strtoul still accepts 'FFFFFFFFF' and 'a!!!!'-like inputs...

Comment: @ChristianMarkRamosGodoy: So don't use `strtoul`, use `std::stoul` instead.

Comment: Note that @BoBTFish is talking about [std::stoul](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stoul), **not** `strtoul`. Have a look at the reference in the link.

Comment: @BoBTFish: I believe that is worth an answer. Especially since the answers so far only talk about the (defective) C way.

Comment: @MatthieuM. I added a `stoul` to my answer since the original question was based on `strtoul` I answered that first.

Comment: @MatthieuM @BoBTFish I forgot to mention that I am using VS2008. I think `stoul` is not supported.

Comment: @ChristianMarkRamosGodoy: Indeed...

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the "old C-style strings", then you can add extra checks to see that "all characters were taken" by passing a `char *` to the `strtoul` call.

In other words:

```
 char *end_ptr = NULL;
 ....
 errno = 0;
 holder = strtoul(buffer, &end_ptr, 16);
```

The `end_ptr` will point at the character one past the accepted input, so if you enter "a!!!!!", it will point at a '!'.

```
 if (end_ptr != '\0')  // Should point at "end of string marker". 
 {
     ... do something to indicate error. 
 }
```

To detect overflow, you will have to rely on `errno`:

```
if (errno != 0)
{
    ... deal with errors here . 
}
```

Obviously, you can do:

```
if (errno != 0 || *end_ptr != '\0')
{
    .... deal with errors. 
}
```

Using the C++ `std:stoul()` function will throw an exception, so the C++ style solution would be something like:

```
try
{
    holder = std::stoul(buffer);
}
catch(...)
{
    ... deal with error ... 
}
```

Comment: As far as I can tell if the value is out of range `end_ptr` will still point to a `\0` and you will have to check the actual returned value and `errno`.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour: The descriptions I can find are rather unclear as to exactly what counts as a "invalid character", but you I think you are right.

Comment: @Mats Petersson I used the std:stoul() but the problem is that when I enter a!!!, the unsigned long variable turns to 10 which is the equivalent of A...

Comment: Hmm, ok, so you'll probably have to resort to the above trickery with `strtoul` then. Or, use `stringstream` as SteveL explains.

Comment: @Mats Petersson OK! I'll try them! Thank you!

Comment: @ChristianMarkRamosGodoy If you pass in the second argument to `stoul` as in my example the value will be `1` but the length of the string is greater than `1` so you know that it could not convert the whole string and you have an issue.

Comment: @Shafik Yaghmour The problem with your code is that when I initialize `holder="a!!!!"`, the output still remains 10 which is the value of hex A.

Comment: @ChristianMarkRamosGodoy Did you check the value of `pos` versus the length of the string? You have to do the error checking in order to know if the value returned in valid or not, that is the way it works. Both methods have their trade off you have to pick which one works for you but both require some manual checking on your part, there is no way around that.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I am using VS2008. I think `stoul` is not supported.

Comment: That is correct. Either `strtoul` still exists, but not `strtoull`.

Answer (score 1):

So if you look at this document for [`strtoul`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtoul) you will see this under the `Return Value` section:

> If the converted value falls out of range of corresponding return type, range error occurs and ULONG_MAX or ULLONG_MAX is returned.

So for out of range check you need code similar to this:

```
if ( ( holder == ULONG_MAX || holder == ULLONG_MAX ) && errno == ERANGE)
```

For the `a!!!!` case looking back at the same document, you will see:

> The functions sets the pointer pointed to by str_end to point to the character past the last character interpreted. If str_end is NULL, it is ignored.

you are currently passing in `NULL` but if you pass in an argument:

```
char *p;
holder = strtoul (buffer,&p,16);
```

you can now check whether if `*p` is a NULL terminator and if so then you processed all the characters otherwise you know you had an issue.

You also have the option of using [`stoul`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stoul) which throw the following exceptions `std::invalid_argument` if no conversion could be performed and `std::out_of_range` if the converted value would fall out of the range of the result type.

For example you could do as follows:

```
std::string str1(n) ;
size_t pos ;

try
{
   holder = std::stoul( str1, &pos, 16 ) ;
}
catch( std::invalid_argument e )
{
    std::cout << "Invalid argument" << std::endl ;
}
catch ( std::out_of_range  e )
{
    std::cout << "Out of range" << std::endl ;
}
```

`pos` will be the index of the last character processed, in your case if `pos != str1.length()` then it could not process the whole string and your have a problem.

Answer (score 0):

As other posters have said - use `stoul` if you have it.

If you don't, you might be able to do something like:

```
std::istringstream strm( buffer );

unsigned long holder = 1;
strm >> std::hex >> holder;

if( strm.fail() )
         // out-of-range

if( ! strm.eof() )
         // didn't read all available characters - catches "A!!!"
```