# How to use stoull on VS2008?

Tags: c++, string, visual-studio-2008, unsigned-long-long-int

Do you have any idea on how to use `stoull` on Visual Studio 2008? I want to convert string to unsigned long long. Thanks!

Comment: I don't think VS2008 has any C++11.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee404774.aspx - if you click on "other versions", it shows that it isn't available before 2010. Try using `stringstream` instead?

Comment: @chris Is there any way I can implement `stoull` or any other method that I can use to achieve unsigned long long?

Comment: @Mats Petersson OK! I'll try that up! Thanks!

Comment: @ChristianMarkRamosGodoy, `long long` wasn't a standard type before C++11, so I'm not completely sure.

Comment: @ChristianMarkRamosGodoy As was pointed out to you by [an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17814627/583833) in your other question, you can use stringstreams for this.

Comment: In VC2008 and earier, you can use a (non-standard) `_strtoui64`; [see documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/85zk715d.aspx). `__int64` is the same type as `long long` with these compilers.

Answer (score 0):

For stoll/stoull replacement please look here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/czcad93k%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

you can make use of :
_atoi64, _atoi64_l, _wtoi64, _wtoi64_l
which converts a string to a 64-bit integer.

hope this helps!! 
Happy coding,
-codevik